# How to fix this error which randomly makes the screen black before loading its content?

Tags: android, error-handling

I'm recoding the code other coder made. It uses SAX parser among other things. When I load the main screen, the screen is first black (like frozen), but then the layout elements are loaded.

This does not happen often, but randomly. I've noticed that this error is caught `getPackageInfoItem() NameNotFoundException`. Here is the stack trace:

```
07-10 13:11:13.835: ERROR/PackageInfoItemFactory(16118): getPackageInfoItem() NameNotFoundException
android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.app.android
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:214)
at com.sec.android.app.controlpanel.PackageInfoItemFactory.updatePackageInfoItem(PackageInfoItemFactory.java:88)
at com.sec.android.app.controlpanel.PackageInfoItemFactory.updatePackageInfoItem(PackageInfoItemFactory.java:67)
at com.sec.android.app.controlpanel.PackageIntentReceiver.onReceive(PackageIntentReceiver.java:27)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2131)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:127)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: @Caner Why edit? I did not know that English UK is not allowed on stack community.

Comment: Of course UK English is allowed, but "randoumly" does not even exist in British English: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/british/?q=randoumly

Answer (score 1):

```
When I load the main screen, the screen is first black (like frozen), but then the layout elements are loaded.
```

I'm sure you are doing some expensive UI blocking work in your activity's Main UI thread. Spo do it Asynchronously put those code in [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). So it will not block your UI.

```
getPackageInfoItem() NameNotFoundException
```

This exception is thrown when a given package, application, or component name can not be found. So sometime its possible given component doesn't have a name attribute.You have to handle this exception in your code as it happen randomly.

Comment: Regarding the other thing, I would love to surround it with try/catch if I only new where is it happening. Nowhere in the code, I can find usage of `getPackageInfoItem()`. So who may call it and where does the call may happen?

Comment: (As I think you already know this) Look at your application's code and find the use of **com.sec.android.app.controlpanel.PackageInfoItemFactory.** class, it cause the exception. For using getApplicationInfo() of PackageManager.

Comment: Hm I cannot find any occurrence of such usage, in either case. Do you have any more ideas?